# How to iterating list in a row with lambda fuction in pyspark?

Tags: list, pyspark, rdd

My problem is the following one: i need to loop through row into RDD and for each row I need to loop through a list.
My RDD is:

```
rdd1:
[a,b,c,d]
[f,g,j,k]

rddMinHash=ListRDD.map(lambda j: funct(iterating into list of row j))
```

How can I write the codeinto funct()?

Comment: What are you expecting for `funct()` to do? And what methods did you already tried?

Comment: lambda j iterate over each row of rdd1, funct() is a minhash and has to be applied at each item of the list. The problem is that  minHash doesn't accept a list but just a string, so I have to passe one item per time. I tried with nested lambda functions to loop into rdd rows and the inner lambda funct loop into the list, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Yor approach seems to be valid. Can you update question with code you wrote? Then we can try to find a bug inside.

Comment: rddMinHash=ListRDD.map(lambda j: lambda x : dist(x[0],x[1]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **List Comprehensions** in lambda function

like this `rdd1.map(lambda x: [len(x) for i in x])`

x is row and type is a list.
i is the element in the list.